# Удаление непечатных символов, замена  символов на эквивалентные им символьные коды

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Необходимо удалить в строке все непечатные символы и произвести замену `"` на `quot`, `<` на `lt`, `>` на `gt`.
Грубо говоря, согласно пункту "Условия и рекомендации по передаче данных" http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/goods-prices/technical-requirements.xml

Как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс HTML::Entities

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings; 
use HTML::Entities;

my $input = ">hello<&";
print encode_entities($input), "\n"; # &gt;hello&lt;&amp;
```

Более подробно в [официальной документации](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/Entities.pm)

Comment: Дополню свой ответ, воспользуйтесь лучше классом [HTML::Escape][1], он намного быстрее

[1]: http://search.cpan.org/~tokuhirom/HTML-Escape-1.09/lib/HTML/Escape.pm